# Facebook4j - GetUserLikes returns null

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get all the pages the user liked like this :

```
ResponseList<Like> likes = facebook.getUserLikes(string id, reading);
```

But I got the below response for println(likes)

```
PagableListImpl{count=null, paging=null, summary=null, []}
```

I have authorized the permission of user_like

Comment: why not use "me" instead of the user id? did you debug the access token to make sure it really includes the user_likes permission?

Comment: Because I will do it on several users, how can I debug access token ?